# Selenium scraping data off multiple JavaScript pages with scrapy-selenium module

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, scrapy

Hello heroes of the modern world,

I'm currently working on scraping this JS-based webpage https://golden.com/list-of-cryptocurrency-companies/ and this is the code I've implemented so far

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from shutil import which
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException


class ScrapperSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'scrapper'
    allowed_domains = ['golden.com']
    start_urls = ['https://golden.com/list-of-cryptocurrency-companies/']
    current_page = 1


    def __init__(self):
        
        chrome_path = which('chromedriver')
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chrome_path)  


    def parse(self, response):
        driver = self.driver 
        number_of_pages = 27

        for i in range(number_of_pages): 

            url = 'https://golden.com/list-of-cryptocurrency-companies/'
            driver.get(url + str(i+1))
            driver.set_window_size(1920, 1080)

            all_results = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//select[contains(@class, 'PageSize')]/option[3]").click()

            new_table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "NewTable__body")))

            driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")

            import time
            time.sleep(5)

            driver.implicitly_wait(10)
                    # driver.find_element

            self.html = driver.page_source
         

            resp = Selector(text=self.html)
            for currency in resp.xpath("//div[@class='NewTable__body']/div"):
                exchange_name = currency.xpath('.//div[1]/div/div/div/span/a/span/text()').get()
                website = currency.xpath(".//div[3]/div/div/div/div/span/a/@href").get()

                industry_type = currency.xpath(".//div[4]/div/div/div/div")
                for industry in industry_type:
                    industry_1 = industry.xpath(".//div[1]/span/a/span/text()").get()
                    industry_2 = industry.xpath(".//div[2]/span/a/span/text()").get()
                    industry_3 = industry.xpath(".//div[3]/span/a/span/text()").get()
                    industry_4 = industry.xpath(".//div[4]/span/a/span/text()").get()
                    industry_5 = industry.xpath(".//div[5]/span/a/span/text()").get()


                    
                    location = currency.xpath(".//div[5]/div/div/div/div/div/span/a/span/text()").get()
                

                    yield {
                        'ex_name': exchange_name,
                        'url': website,
                        'industry_1': industry_1,
                        'industry_2': industry_2,
                        'industry_3': industry_3,
                        'industry_4': industry_4,
                        'indsutry_5': industry_5,
                        'location': location

                    }
            
        driver.close()   
        driver.quit()
```

My main issue is with the webpage changing from https://golden.com/list-of-cryptocurrency-companies/ to https://golden.com/list-of-cryptocurrency-companies/2 and then goes back immediately to the original form, without scraping anything else off any of the other pages. Now for the life of me, I can't seem to understand what is going on as I've literally been working on this for an entire week now.

Would be beyond grateful if someone can help me out here coz I'm genuinely clueless

Comment: though it appears to go back to first url, it still loads the correct url after loading. You have to wait until the page is properly loaded.

Comment: @Sureshmani So would you suggest inserting an implicit wait after selecting the URL and the beginning of the for loop or where would you reckon? Still slowly absorbing how the logic of this Is playing out! Just to reiterate, the content of the first page is scrapped successfully after it's loaded, then during 2nd loop, webpage changes to new URL, then reverts back immediately to original form

Comment: I tried to iterate the url like you did it here. here is my observation - when the driver clicks for next url, the page url navigates back to https://golden.com/list-of-cryptocurrency-companies/ and then once loaded it shows the correct url - https://golden.com/list-of-cryptocurrency-companies/2.

Comment: My suggestion is that you have to add explicit wait either waiting for the url to become the correct url or wait for the new table loads. @Karim Nabil

Comment: @Sureshmani Okay so i've tried waiting for the new table to load up with   -----new_table = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CLASS_NAME, "NewTable__body"))) , but it didn't change any thing. URL still changes. How would u suggest Implementing an explicit wait for the URL to become the correct one since it's always changing?

Comment: I have posted a sample code as answer here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an sample code on how to wait until the url changes to something. This will scrape company name from each page.

```
number_of_pages = 27

for i in range(number_of_pages):
    url = 'https://golden.com/list-of-cryptocurrency-companies/'+ str(i+1)
    driver.get(url)
    # wait upto 10 seconds for url changes
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.url_to_be(url))
    companies = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='QueryResults']//span[@class='TopicLink__text']")
    print("Printing from page#" , i+1)
    for company in companies:
        print(company.text)

 
 
driver.close()   
driver.quit()
```

**Here is the output:**

```
Printing from page# 1
Temtum
CRYPTOCURRENCY
BLOCKCHAIN
Tortola
National Digital Asset Exchange Inc. (NDAX)
CRYPTOCURRENCY
...
Printing from page# 2
Dentacoin
CRYPTOCURRENCY
BLOCKCHAIN
HEALTHCARE
Netherlands
Waves Platform
...
```

Comment: Cool okay that makes sense. It's still not preventing the URL from changing back to its original form tho :( Do you know of any other approaches to stop this change or check that the URL has been changed successfully?

Comment: After this wait, you should be able to scrap data from the new page. is it still not working?

Comment: Yeah it hasn't changed the code's behavior still. Also shouldn't this solution work only with the first 2 pages as the new_url will only represent 2nd page, but wont' help with the rest of 27?

Comment: See my updated answer. i am able to scrape the company name from each page successfully. if you apply the same solution to your code, you should be able to scrape it without any issues.

Comment: What a legend. Thank you so much man, really appreciate your patience!